# how can I handle signals to change ctrl+c and ctrl+z?

Tags: c, linux, signals

How can I make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> using signals in order to confirm question to stop process if user put y to quit, and how can I send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> ?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i=0;

void plus()
{
    i++;

}

void close()
{
    printf("\nControl^c has pressed %d times\n",i);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    signal(2,plus);
    signal(20,close);
    getchar();

}
```

Using this code you can count how much times you press ^c and the program exit when you press ^z

Comment: It's not safe to use `printf()` in a signal handler, probably the same apples to `exit()`.  Also, use the defines in signal.h not bare numbers.

Comment: Definitely use defines and remember to use signal safe variables/functions listed in `signal` man pages. Also it does not explain how to send `SIGSTP` (ctrl+z)